# Error: [@formatjs/intl Error MISSING_DATA] Missing locale data

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

My project that I am working on is using @formatjs/intl library. And one of the used locales is non existing 'la' locale. I need to figure out a workaround for this locale, the best way would be to somehow set that 'la' locale would use existing 'es' locale data, the other option would be somehow to hide this error. Do you have any advices? Thank you.

Error:

```
utils.js:20 Error: [@formatjs/intl Error MISSING_DATA] Missing locale data forlocale: "la" in Intl.NumberFormat. Using default locale: "en" as fallback. See https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl#runtime-requirements for more details 

at new MissingDataError (error.js:50:1)
at createIntl (create-intl.js:42:1)
at createIntl (provider.js:62:1)
at new IntlProvider (provider.js:82:1)
at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12716:1)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17425:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23940:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```